# Utility of notification 'UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification'

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cordova

I am using Cordova 2.1.0 for IOS app development.  Since, I am new to app development, I have a very basic question.

I am using `applicationDidEnterBackground` method to handle app control when app enters background. But i want to understand the utility of `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` which is sent when the app is entering the background. In what way can i use this notification and other notifications(like `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification`, etc.) sent by the system. What is the USP of these notifications.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, the method `applicationDidEnterBackground:` tells the `UIApplication`'s delegate that the application is now in the background.  In Cocoa, many delegate messages have corresponding `UINotification`s that are also sent.  This is no exception.

According to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html):

> The application also posts a `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` notification around the same time it calls this method to give interested objects a chance to respond to the transition.

Therefore, if there are objects in your object graph that need to respond to the state transition, they can observe this notification.  I'm not sure there's really an unstated purpose beyond allowing all objects in the graph to respond to application state transition.  I suppose if you had a long-running task to perform somewhere down the object hierarchy when the application transitions to background task you could use `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:` in a manner similar to what you do in the `applicationDidEnterBackground`.

**EDIT:**

```
//  example, save NSArray *_myArray to disk when app enters background
//  this is contrived, and untested, just meant to show how you can
//  observe the UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification and save state
//  in an arbitrary point in the object graph. (as opposed, or in addition to, the
//  application's delegate.

//  long-running tasks, e.g. web service connections, etc. will need to 
//  get a background task identifier from the UIApplication and manage that.

__block id enteredBackground = nil;
NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
enteredBackground = [center addObserverForName:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                        object:nil
                                         queue:nil
                                    usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
                                        [_myArray writeToFile:@"/path/to/you/file" atomically:YES];

                     }];
```

Comment: Thanks FYI. If u can give an example on how i can use this notification in the app..It will be really helpful.thanks.